# iframe の要素をeventListenerのloadで取得できない

Tags: javascript

loadでイベントリスナーを仕掛けてもgetElementsByTagNameでiframeの要素を取れません。
どうすればよいでしょうか？iframeDocはグローバル変数です。

```
window.addEventListener('load',async function(){
 let iframeBody = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.body;
 
 observer.observe(iframeBody, config);
 });
```

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]);`が`undefined`を出力するというのが解決したい問題ですか？試してみましたが再現できませんでした。再現可能な最小のコードを提示して下さい。

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko やりたいことは、画面がロードされたときにdocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe')で、iframe要素を取得したいということです。そのためにwindow.addEventListener('load', func)をしたのですが、取得できません。console 上で、直接document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')を実行すると要素取得ができます。

Comment: 私が書いてみたコードです。Console出力を確認してください。https://codepen.io/itagagaki/pen/OJvNrrP

Comment: `iframeDoc` というグローバル変数が質問文から無くなっています。
おそらく、その変数に取得した要素を代入して後から参照しようとしているのだと思います。
そうだとすると、その変数を参照するタイミングが問題かも知れません。
いずれにしろ、[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、質問のコードを再現可能にしてみて下さい。

Comment: @mjy iframe内でjsファイルが読み込まれていたので、document 自体がiframe内のdocument を指していました。なので上記のコードで存在しないiframe内のiframeを探してしている状態でした。お二人共ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

> iframe内でjsファイルが読み込まれていたので、document 自体がiframe内のdocument を指していました。なので上記のコードで存在しないiframe内のiframeを探してしている状態でした。
> —— [コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89849/iframe-%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e3%82%92eventlistener%e3%81%aeload%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment102004_89849)より

とのことです。